# Given $a_i$ -$r$ paths $P_i$ in a planar graph construct a tree spanning $a_i$ such that each root to leaf path intersects few $P_i$

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, tree

Suppose I am given distinct nodes $a_1,a_2,.., a_l, r$  and edge disjoint  $a_i$-$r$ paths $P_i$ for each $i$ in a planar graph $G$.

I wish to construct a tree $T$  connecting $a_1,a_2,.., a_l, r$  that minimizes the maximum over all $a_i$ the number of $P_i$ that an $a_i$-$r$ path of $T$ shares an edge with.

How small can we guarantee such a quantity is in terms of $l$?
That is to say fix $l$ and consider all possible choices of $a_i$-$r$ paths $P_i$ how small can we choosing $T$, guarantee the maximum over all $a_i$ the number of $P_i$ that an $a_i$-$r$ path of $T$ shares an edge with.

Comment: Can you explain the question bit more clearly. Do you count the number of edges where $T$ intersects $P$? If yes, isn't the answer unbounded even for $l=1$?

Comment: @Laakeri  I think you misunderstand I'm not minimizing the number of edges of a   $a_i$-$r$ path  but the number of P_i that it intersects  (where by intersect I mean share an edge)

Comment: This question is not clear at all. It should be rewritten to make it more clear. The way I understand it, the answer can be 0 (because there is a $G$ that contains a tree disjoint from each $P_i$), or the answer can be $l$ (because if $G$ is a star, it contains only one spanning tree).

Comment: @domotorp I clarified that we fix $l$ and consider all possible choices of $a_i$-$r$ paths $P_i$ how small can we guarantee to make...